# I could not see the objects from a public AWS S3 bucket. When I am trying to access image through url, it was showing the following error

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, browser, access-denied

I am trying access an image from my s3 bucket(I made it public) through the object url. But it is showing the following error:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>F5440E7960C1B243</RequestId>
<HostId>A4/TJ9eD6IvJ3ck6meOYsDiaEuRXU****************0pb1qv1A9FnwJGj5wSgtjb********=</HostId>
</Error>
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I’m not clear what you are asking here. Neither the XML document containing the error message, not the image that you don’t have permission to view are HTML documents so why would you want the browser to treat either of them as HTML? What would that look like?

Comment: I am having an image object stored in my s3 bucket which I made public. So, if I search my object url in my browser, it should be able to show the image, but instead I was shown the above message.

Comment: What actually happened here was  that I added my objects while the bucket was private and then made it public. The objects that were added earlier remained private and had to make those objects public individually.

Answer (score 1):

This file is being returned because the object you're trying to access is not publicly accessible (or does not exist), please check the following:

- Bucket Policy allows public (`*` principal) access for `GetObject` at least for this Object.
- There is no ACL that is denying access to your object.
- Your S3 bucket does not have the block public access option enabled.

This is being interpreted as XML because it is XML, it won't render as HTML as none of the components of this response are valid HTML components.

Your browser would be interpreting it by the `Content-Type` header that is returned with the response. If you wanted to interpret it with a different header you would need to add another layer in front that would service this response with a `Content-Type` of either `text/xml` or `application/xml`. However, as I mentioned this will not be rendered with styling because the object does not exist.

If you're using an S3 website you should look at the [error document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CustomErrorDocSupport.html) to be returned when an error (such as no object or access denied) is returned. Otherwise you can use a CloudFront distribution in front that can [return a static HTML page in the event your S3 origin returns an error](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/custom-error-pages.html).